# How do I test whether an object returned from Eloquent query is set?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm testing to see if a user already has a record (d) in the database.

My query:

```
$userResults = Results::where('d','=',Input::get('d'))
                      ->where('user','=',Input::get('user'),'AND')->get();
```

with `var_dump` returns

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#333 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

when empty or an array of results if there.

How do I test the object for `isset`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use `count` to check the result:

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection implements Countable interface
if (count($userResults) === 0) {
  // empty result
}
```

or just use the **[isEmpty](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#381-389)** method:

```
if ($userResults->isEmpty()) {
  // empty result
}
```

Comment: added kudos for the link to documentation. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Collection method for this:

```
$userResults->isEmpty(); // true / false
```

Or count since Collection implements Countable interface

```
count($userResults); // 0 if empty

if (empty($userResults)) { // do the job }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($userResults)){
   //you criteria
}
```

OR

```
if(empty($userResults)){
       //you criteria
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($userResults->count()){
     //your code
    }
```